# Ticket bot doesn't create channels or categories

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Full error:

```py
    [2023-08-12 20:05:06] [ERROR   ] discord.ui.view: Ignoring exception in view     <TicketPanelView timeout=None children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.secondary: 2>     url=None disabled=False label='Create Ticket' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='✉️'     id=None> row=None>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File     "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-        packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
            await item.callback(interaction)
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ticket bot\main2.py", line 15,     in create_ticket
            if interaction.user.id in open_tickets:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'`
```

Full code:

```py
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

    class TicketPanelView(discord.ui.View):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label='Create Ticket', emoji='✉️')
    async def create_ticket(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if interaction.user.id in open_tickets:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You already have an open ticket.",     ephemeral=True)
            return

            category = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, name='Tickets')
            if not category:
                category = await interaction.guild.create_category('Tickets')

            ticket_channel = await category.create_text_channel(f'ticket-        {interaction.user.display_name}')
            await ticket_channel.set_permissions(interaction.user, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)

            await ticket_channel.send(f'Welcome {interaction.user.mention}! Your ticket has been created.')
            await interaction.response.send_message('Creating a new ticket...', ephemeral=True)
        
            open_tickets[interaction.user.id] = ticket_channel.id
            self.stop()


    @bot.command()
    async def panel(ctx):
       embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Test',
            description='test', 
            color=discord.Color.blue()
        )
        view = TicketPanelView()
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

    # Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with your actual bot token
    bot.run('token')`
```

Clicking the “Create Ticket” button gives me the error.

It gives me that error when I click the “Create Ticket” button, I tried asking ChatGPT and asking a couple of friends, but I still have the same error. I also tried some ticket bots from YouTube, GitHub and more, but I can't find a bot that does what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You've swapped the position of the parameters `button` and `interaction`, hence, `discord.ui.Button` was parsed into `interaction`.

```
class TicketPanelView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label='Create Ticket', emoji='✉️')
    async def create_ticket(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
```